# C# Text don't display on another form after double clicking an item in listbox

Tags: c#

I'm doing a winform which consist a listbox (listbox10) with some items on it. When I doubleclick an item, it will show another form (Form3) which consist a textbox (textbox1) and the textbox's text is the item I select. Below is my coding.

```
Form3 msgForm3;
private void listBox10_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    msgForm3 = new Form3();
    textBox1.Text = listBox10.SelectedItem.ToString();
    msgForm3.Show();
}
```

But somehow I don't know why, the textbox is always empty. Anything wrong with my coding?

Comment: You are not accessing the textbox on form3.

Comment: Any example on the Setup(string text), dash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `textBox1` you are accessing is not on `msgForm3`. to access the one on `msgForm3` use (as the other answers have mentioned)

```
msgForm3.textBox1.Text = listBox10.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

but since all form controls are `private` by default you can either change its protection level inside `Form3.Designer.cs` to `public` (or `internal` ) :

```
public System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1;
```

or add the text that should go in `textbox1` as a parameter in Form3 constructor :

```
public Form3(string text)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.textBox1.Text = text;
}
```

and when your create an instance of Form3 use

```
msgForm3 = new Form3(listBox10.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

Comment: +1 this is my preferred route too, although I would add a property to the form as well.

Comment: Another thing, what if it's not just the textbox's text have to change, a label also have to change. how?

Comment: Use the same method: either pass the values you want as parameters to your constructor or change the protection level of the controls you want to access from other forms.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing the textbox1 is a control inside msgForm3 then the right syntax should be

```
msgForm3.textBox1.Text = listBox10.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

This requires changing the property Modifiers from Private to Public for the textBox1 using the Form Designer property window.
I don't recommended this change. It is better to pass the new value inside the constructor of msgForm3 like this

```
msgForm3 = new Form3(listBox10.SelectedItem.ToString());  
msgForm3.Show();
```

and then in the constructor of msgForm3 add

```
public Form3(string initialValue)  
{  
    InitializeComponent();  
    this.textBox1.Text = initialValue;  
}
```

or you can add a public method to your Form3 class like this

public void InitText(string initialValue)
   {
       this.textBox1.Text = initialValue;
   }

and call in this way

```
msgForm3 = new Form3();  
msgForm3.InitText(listBox10.SelectedItem.ToString());
msgForm3.Show();
```

Comment: Steve, I've tried it but an error appear saying the textbox is inaccessible due to its protection level. What is it mean?

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can access the member of the other form.

```
msgForm3 = new Form3();
msgForm3.textBox1.Text = listBox10.SelectedItem.ToString();
msgForm3.Show();
```

**EDIT:**

From the `Form3.Designer.cs` file just change protection level from `private` to `public`.

Replace

```
private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1;
```

To

```
public System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1;
```

Comment: Vishal Suthar, I've tried it but an error appear saying the textbox is inaccessible due to its protection level. What is it mean?

Comment: change its protection level from `private` to `public` in Form2.Designer.cs