# C# how to pass the value of form3 back to form1

Tags: c#

This question is the followup to the following question:
[C# Text don't display on another form after double clicking an item in listbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12795668/c-sharp-text-dont-display-on-another-form-after-double-clicking-an-item-in-list)

Now I have typed my value in the textbox of form3. How am I going to pass back the value to form1 to show it in the listbox10 after pressing "OK" in form3? Below is my form3 coding but it don't work:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    //This is the coding for "OK" button.
    int selectedIndex = listBox10.SelectedIndex;
    listBox10.Items.Insert(selectedIndex, textBox1.Text);
}
```

Comment: Well, the best way to do that is to make a public method in Form1 that receives your data from Form3. In that method you should Invoke delegate that will call another method that will change the data in the UI thread of the Form1. In Form3 you should call that method from Form1. This implies that you need to have a reference of the Form1 in Form3. You can pass that reference using Form3's constructor.

Comment: winform or webform? I guess it's winform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put public property on form3:

```
public partial class form3 : Form
{
    public String SomeName
    {
        get
        {
            return textbox1.Text;
        }
    }

    ...
    private void buttonOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        Close();
    }

    private void buttonCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
        Close();
    }
 }
```

In form1, where you are open form3, after ShowDialog, you will write:

```
if (form3.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{

    int selectedIndex = listBox10.SelectedIndex;

    if (selectedIndex == -1) //listbox does not have items
        listbox10.Add(form3.SomeValue);
    else
        listBox10.Items.Insert(selectedIndex, form3.SomeName);
}
```

Comment: This solution can invoke exceptions. Passing data between Forms should be made using delegates and Invoke method of the form

Comment: I've try this method, but there's error for listBox10.SelectedIndex as it is equals to -1. How come? Is that the exceptions Nick talking about?

Comment: Do you have items in listbox?

Comment: Yes.. that's why I select it by double clicking it to change the value.

Comment: Well, if you want to add new item at the end, you need to use listbox10.Add(form3.SomeName);

Comment: Its not adding items in the end. I need to add on where I click. That's why I use insert.

Comment: Then you need to check does listbox have items. I changed my code.

Comment: But if use form3.ShowDialog(), I only can use the "X" close button to put the value in listbox10. I won't be able to use the "OK" button I created in form3. How can I use the "OK" button?

Comment: I've tried your code. But now, form3 appear two times. What I mean is, after I put the value in form3 and press OK, another form3 appear with the same value. I have to press OK on this second form3 only it will close and add the value in my listbox. Something wrong?

Comment: Oops... It's just my problem. I write like this: form3.ShowDialog(); if (form3.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK). That's why it showed two times form3. After I deleted one, it's fine now. Thank you very much Danilo Vulovic.

Answer (score 0):

do do something like that:

```
//form1:
public void add(int num)
{
  //add num to the list box.
}
```

now, form3 should get an instance of form1 in the constructor, and save it:

```
//in form3:
private form form1_i
public form3(form i_form1)
{
  .
  .
  .
 form1_i = i_form1;
}
```

and on button click in form3, call the fumction `add` in form1.

Comment: Any example on this elyashiv?

Answer (score 0):

It should go like this, this is the safest way to do it, in fact if you are working on Windows Mobile this is the only way that won't crash the application. In desktop versions it can crash in debug versions.

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public string name = "something";
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public delegate void nameChanger(string nme);
    public void ChangeName(string nme)
    {
        this.name = nme;
    }
    public void SafeNameChange(string nme)
    {
        this.Invoke(new nameChanger(ChangeName), new object[] { nme });
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form3 f3 = new Form3(this);
        f3.Show();
    }
```

}

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        Form1 ff;
        public Form2(Form1 firstForm)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ff = firstForm;
        }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ff.SafeNameChange("something different from the Form1");
        this.Close();
    }
}
```