# Edit label control from other form

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# Text don’t display on another form after double clicking an item in listbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12795668/c-sharp-text-dont-display-on-another-form-after-double-clicking-an-item-in-list)

I am beginner in c#. I want to edit a label `lblText` present in a form `subForm` from other form `mainForm` whenever user clicks the buttons `btnHigh` and `btnLow`(these buttons are in `mainForm`).

```
 For btnHigh_Click event  --> lblText should have text "high"
 For btnLow_Click event   --> lblText should have text "low"
```

I tried the below code :(*not working*)

**btnHigh_Click Event**

```
        subForm sf = new subForm ();
        sf.ShowDialog();
        sf.lblText.Text = "High";  // lblText --> modifier is public
```

What i am doing wrong here?

Please Help

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to change the value first before showing the form,

```
    subForm sf = new subForm ();
    sf.lblText.Text = "High";  
    sf.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: It doesn't matter, as `Text` is a property that forces the GUI to update when changed

Comment: @Nacereddine he said that `lblText` is public.

Comment: @JohnWoo I just read that...I need more coffee.

Comment: @Desolator no it Does matter,  the code (*if shown as modal*) will not resume until the form has been closed.

Answer (score 1):

What did you write is wrong

```
subForm sf = new subForm (); 
sf.ShowDialog(); 
sf.lblText.Text = "High";  // lblText --> modifier is public
```

The `ShowDialog` method block the current form and open another one. Thats cause the row 
`sf.lblText.Text = "High";` to "run" after your `subForm` will closed.

The best way to do that, is not to make your text box as public, but you can deliver the data in the constructor like that:

**In the subForm class add the constructor:**

```
public subForm(string strText)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.lblText.Text = strText; // Must be after the InitializeComponent method
}
```

**In the caller to subForm write that:**

```
subForm sf = new subForm ("High");              
sf.ShowDialog();
```

This is the corret way to do that.
Its better to avoid using the public permission for this kind of things. Because all the "world" out of `subForm` do not need to know that it have lable called lblText, and for managing the access to `subForm` data.

Answer (score 0):

you can Create Public Property for subForm :

```
public string lblText{get;set;}
```

and set this Property on Load Form :

```
 public subForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
    lblText.Text=lblText;
        }
```

and :

```
subForm sf = new subForm ();
sf.lblText = "High";  
sf.ShowDialog();
```